# Using namespaced functions for event listeners

Tags: javascript

I have written some namespaced javascript and I'm having trouble binding to window events (such as scroll, resize) and retaining access to my instance of the app, for example:

```
var app = new function() {

  this.init = function() {
    var self = this;
    window.onresize = self.resize;
  };

  this.resize = function() {
    var self = this;
    console.log(self); // Gives me the window!
  };

};
app.init();
```

I'd rather not have to declare the function then and there with `window.onresize = function()...`, because I want to be able to call my `app.resize()` function independently too. Is there a better way to do this within the scope of my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No reason why you can't do both:

```
window.onresize = function() {self.resize();};
// calls `self.resize` with the context of `self`
```

Comment: This solves it, thank you - just thought it not very elegant, so was wondering if there was a better way.

Comment: @toomanyredirects You could do `window.onresize = self.resize.bind(self);`, but it's not compatible with older browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Niet the Dark Absol's answer is correct and shorter, but learning about [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to set the value of `this` inside functions changed my life! Maybe it will help you too:

```
window.onresize = function() {

  // calls self.resize() with the value of `this` set to `self`
  self.resize.call(self);

};
```

Comment: Redundant - `self.resize()` already uses `self` as the context.

Comment: Yes, I said your answer was correct and shorter. I just remember grappling with the same issue and have found using `.call()` to be the most helpful in some situations.

Comment: Thanks @ZougenMoriver, I've not tried using `call()` or `apply()` yet. I think you're right that @niet-the-dark-absol has the best solution for me in this instance, but thanks for the pointer.